# Increment conditionally pandas

Tags: python, pandas, logging, time

I have a pandas dataframe with the following conditions:

- Each record has a group, date and indicator if an event happened
- Daily records for each group (not necessarily the same time frame for
  each group)
- Sorted by group, date

I need to implement a counter column that starts at the first event for a group, and only increments when (counter < 3*numEvents).

- if counter = 1 and numevents = 1 -> counter += 1
- if counter = 3 and numevents = 1 -> do nothing

The counter can only increment 3 times without another event happening. if its stuck at a multiple of 3 for multiple records, then once another event happens that allows it to increment it still needs to only increment by 1.

Example DataFrame

```
group        date  event  numEvents         Counter
    A  2020-08-05      0          0               0
    A  2020-08-06      1          1               1
    A  2020-08-07      0          1               2
    A  2020-08-08      0          1               3
    A  2020-08-09      0          1               3
    A  2020-08-10      0          1               3
    A  2020-08-11      1          2               4
    A  2020-08-12      0          2               5
    A  2020-08-13      0          2               6
    A  2020-08-14      0          2               6
    B  2020-08-05      1          1               1
    B  2020-08-06      1          2               2
    B  2020-08-07      0          2               3
    B  2020-08-08      0          2               4
    B  2020-08-09      0          2               5
    B  2020-08-10      0          2               6
    B  2020-08-11      0          2               6
    B  2020-08-12      0          2               6
    B  2020-08-13      0          2               0
    B  2020-08-14      0          2               0
```

Code to generate example dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
base = datetime.datetime.today()
numdays = 10
date_list = [(base - datetime.timedelta(days=x)).date() for x in range(numdays)]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['group', 'date'])
for group in ['A', 'B']:
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'group': group, 'date': date_list})
    df = df.append(tmp)
df = df.sort_values(['group', 'date'])

groupA_events = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
groupB_events = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
events = groupA_events + groupB_events
df['event'] = events
df['numEvents'] = df.groupby('group')['event'].cumsum()

df['Counter'] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
```

The main issue here is that I cant figure out how to conditionally increment a column based on itself. Ive tried using .cumsum() but havent figured out a way to use it that works for this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Richie, thanks for the input. I'm not exactly sure what you are referring to but please see the revision I just made.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the logic needed to obtain the expected results, but here are a couple techniques that might be useful.

- True and False are represented as 1 and 0.
- You can use this with multiplication and cumulative sums.
- Also, `.shift()` can bring a value from an earlier (or later) row to the current row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
     'flag_1': [True] * 3 + [False] * 3, 'flag_2': [True, False] * 3})

# get previous x and current x on same row
df['prev_x'] = df['x'].shift(1)  

# multiply by boolean
df['y'] = df['x'] * df['flag_1']

# cumulative sum of boolean (conditional increment)
df['z'] = df['flag_2'].cumsum()

print(df)

    x  flag_1  flag_2  prev_x   y  z
0  10    True    True     NaN  10  1
1  20    True   False    10.0  20  1
2  30    True    True    20.0  30  2
3  40   False   False    30.0   0  2
4  50   False    True    40.0   0  3
5  60   False   False    50.0   0  3
```

Finally, compare `.transform(min)` versus `.min()` with groupby (using transform gives back the same number of rows as the original data frame).

Comment: Hi, thank you for this advice! One issue i'm having is that the condition if the counter increments is based on the counter itself. So therefore when using shift it doesnt properly reflect the condition (atleast the way I tried). I added some clarity to my question, could you please take another look at it? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This was a huge help for me in solving a problem.